# Deserialise Json Object in C#code

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, deserialization

I am working on a Angular/Web API application. This is a project that i keep myself busy with at home so that i can familiarize myself with the new technologies and ways to integrate services.

Everything went well until i had to start updating data. I am making use of WebApi 2.1

The problem is that from angular I need to update the Employee object however when i pass an ID and the Employee Json Object then it does not deserialize correctly when it gets to the C# code.

This is the code that i use when i pass my data from the Client to the server :

`employeeService.update({ id: $routeParams.employeeId }, { 'employee': result.object });`

The result.object look as follows :

```
[prototype]: {...}
    $id: "1"
    $promise: {...}
    $resolved: true
    ContactNo: "0834541784"
    Courses: [[object Object],[object Object]]
    Division: {...}
    DivisionId: 3
    EmployeeCode: "E9955"
    EmployeeId: 4
    EmployeeType: null
    EmployeeTypeId: 1
    FirstName: "Gytis"
    Gender: 2
    IdNumber: "8311016262773"
    Nationality: {...}
    NationalityId: 1
    Position: null
    PositionId: 1
    Surname: "Barzdukas"
```

the Employee class that it must map to in C# looks like this :

```
public class Employee 
    {
        [Key]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set;}
        [Required]
        public string EmployeeCode { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string IdNumber { get; set; }
        public string ContactNo { get; set; }
        public Gender Gender { get; set; }
        public int? PositionId { get; set; }
        public int NationalityId { get; set; }
        public int? EmployeeTypeId { get; set; }
        public int DivisionId { get; set; }
        public  Division Division { get; set; }
        public  ICollection<EmployeeCourse> Courses { get; set; }
        public  Position Position { get; set; }
        public  Nationality Nationality { get; set; }
        public  EmployeeType EmployeeType { get; set; }
     }
```

now when the code reaches the C# Web APi update function my ID is populated with the correct EmployeeID however the Employee parameter is blank (empty object). 
[image: empty Parameter..]
When i change this type from employee to Object the code looks like this and i cant get this object to parse into type Employee?
[image]

```
{
  "employee": {
    "EmployeeId": 1,
    "EmployeeCode": "E9584",
    "FirstName": "Carson",
    "Surname": "Alexander",
    "IdNumber": "8704167738384",
    "ContactNo": "0834549632",
    "Gender": 2,
    "PositionId": 1,
    "NationalityId": 1,
    "EmployeeTypeId": 1,
    "DivisionId": 3,
    "Division": {
      "DivisionId": 3,
      "DivisionName": "Garden Court Milpark",
      "Address1": null,
      "Address2": null,
      "Address3": null,
      "PostalCode": null,
      "ContactNo": null,
      "RegionId": 1,
      "EmployeeId": 0,
      "CompanyId": 1,
      "Company": null,
      "Region": null,
      "Employees": [
        {}
      ]
    },
    "Courses": [
      {
        "EmployeeCourseId": 1,
        "EmployeeId": 1,
        "Employee": {},
        "CourseId": 1,
        "Course": {
          "CourseId": 1,
          "CourseCode": "Chem101",
          "CourseDescription": "Chemistry"
        },
        "CourseStatus": "Distinction",
        "CaptureDate": "2014-03-25T21:46:57.093",
        "ExpiryDate": "2015-03-26T21:46:57.09",
        "RegistrationDate": "2014-03-26T21:46:57.093"
      },
      {
        "EmployeeCourseId": 2,
        "EmployeeId": 1,
        "Employee": {},
        "CourseId": 3,
        "Course": {
          "CourseId": 3,
          "CourseCode": "Macro401",
          "CourseDescription": "Macroeconomics"
        },
        "CourseStatus": null,
        "CaptureDate": "2014-03-26T21:46:57.093",
        "ExpiryDate": null,
        "RegistrationDate": null
      },
      {
        "EmployeeCourseId": 3,
        "EmployeeId": 1,
        "Employee": {},
        "CourseId": 4,
        "Course": {
          "CourseId": 4,
          "CourseCode": "cal100",
          "CourseDescription": "Calculus"
        },
        "CourseStatus": null,
        "CaptureDate": "2014-03-26T21:46:57.093",
        "ExpiryDate": null,
        "RegistrationDate": null
      }
    ],
    "Position": null,
    "Nationality": {
      "NationalityId": 1,
      "NationalityDescription": "African",
      "EmployeeId": null
    },
    "EmployeeType": null
  }
}
```

I hope that someone can please help and tell me how can i get this object into the Employee Class

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was the way that i passed my object and also the way i setup my WebApi Routing. After some reading up i changed these things and all is now working fine.

Thanks for all the assistance and suggestions.

I changed the WebApi Route From :

```
[Route("Employee/{id}/{employee}")]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage PutEmployee(int id, EmployeeDto employee)
{...}
```

TO

```
[Route("Employee/{id}")]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage PutEmployee(int id, EmployeeDto employee)
{...}
```

and then on my UI i changed the code as follow :

Angular Controller from :

```
employeeService.update({ id: $routeParams.employeeId }, {employee: result.object});
```

To

```
employeeService.update({ id: $routeParams.employeeId }, result.object);
```

I changed my EmployeeService (update) to look like this now :

```
update: {
       method: "PUT", params: {
       EmployeeCode: "Default",
       FirstName: "Jan",
       Surname: "Solvent",
       IdNumber: "8508174141444",
       ContactNo: "0834411252",
       Gender: "1",
       NationalityId: "1",
       DivisionId: "1"
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't post type of 'object' in MVC. You need to post type of Employee:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutEmployee(int id, Employee employee)
{
    ...
```

You might run into a naming issue and need to rename the 2nd parameter to not have the same name as the type:

```
public HttpResponseMessage PutEmployee(int id, Employee viewModel)
{
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I tried both suggestions that you posted above but still no luck. what i cant understand is that if I set the type as object i do get values back in the parameter. Then when i set it to type Employee i just get an object with all the properties as blank/null.

Comment: Hmmmm, then the problem is with the client posting. You need to have strongly typed arguments in MVC action methods. Have you seen the JSON that gets posted in Fiddler? 


The problem might be one of the fields isn't being deserialized properly. Like "abc" being bound to an int. Have you tried changing the Employee class to only have a few fields?

Comment: I changed to a simple Employee class now with just a firstName and Surname and still when the JSON reach the server the parameter is still empty. I have the code submitted to GitHub [link](git@github.com:Ruandv/Training.git) angular_ui branch.